# Can Android project be nested Inside another Project

Tags: java, android, architecture

I think it's dumb that I might have to write some code twice when I know this is not how this is done. I do not know though how to implement the following or if it's even possible.

```
+ Master Project Folder (Single Github Repo)
+---> Android Project
       +--- Android Code
+---> Heroku Backend Project
       +--- Object Class
```

Is it possible for the Android project to use class from the `Heroku Backend Project` while insuring that the when the Android App is compiled only the referenced classes from the `Heroku Backend Project` is included and not all the other server stuff.

I feel like this makes a lot more sense than writing the same code twice. I just don't know if it's possible/right/how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a project like module library dependency. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html#SettingUpLibraryModule.

Comment: 1. Welcome to Stackoverflow! 2. Would this solution mean that the android project will only be able to use classes from android library projects? Because the classes I need to use are in a normal Java project that runs on Heroku. (Giving you a thumbs up so you can comment)

Comment: You shall convert the Java Project in Android Module and import to the solution structure like on android studio, because the android module have some bindings with gradle.